# Piece-wise Defined Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}2x + 1 & \text{if } x \le 3, \\
8 - 4x & \text{if } x > 3.
\end{cases}$$
Find the sum of all values of $x$ such that $f(x) = 0.$

All I'm getting right now is $x=-\frac{1}{2}\space $ from $\space 2x+1=0$! Is there any method to find the other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: But there are no other solutions! There's only one and you have found it.

Comment: $8-4x=0\implies x=2$, but $f(x)$ is only defined as $8-4x$ if $x>3$, so this isn't a solution.  As Teresa said, you've found the only one.

Comment: See [this](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/qqmfdtqc). The graph of $f$ intersects the $x$-axis only at the point $x=-\tfrac12$.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find the roots of a piecewise function such as this is to solve the equations separately, and then check that the roots you find meet the conditions set out by the function (e.g. $x>5$ or $y=2$).

$$
2x+1=0 \implies 2x=-1 \implies x =-\frac{1}{2}
$$

This solution is valid because $-\frac{1}{2} \leq 3$. Then for the second equation:

$$
8-4x=0 \implies 4x=8 \implies x=2
$$

This solution is not valid because when $f(x)$ is defined as $8-4x$, there is the additional requirement that $x>3$. It looks like the author of this question was trying to trick you with their wording: 'find the sum of all values of $x$...'. Luckily, we are too clever for that! As suggested by  User azifmedrano, try sketching the graph if you are unsure.